# Figure tools not working when overlaying a transparent image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

When overlaying one image on another using `hold on` and transparency (the `'AlphaData'` property), figure tools such as zooming in and the data cursor are not working properly.

This can be seen, for example, in the [Marker-Controlled Watershed Segmentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html) example, by running `ipexwatershed`. The last figure of the example looks like this:

[image: ipexwatershed figure 15]

Using the zoom-in tool on the figure sometimes works, and sometimes results in an invisible figure, though the data is still there, as can be seen by using the data cursor. The data cursor itself behaves somewhat strangely, though it is usable. The black square and tooltip background of the cursor disappear, and only the text is seen.

This issue has already been raised on [MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79352-zoom-not-working-when-using-image-overlay-using-transparency) a year ago, but no solution is provided there.

Comment: well I tried running the example Marker-Controlled Watershed Segmentation with Matlab 2013b and it seems to be working just fine :)

Comment: I'm using 2013b too. As I wrote this issue appears inconsistently. Sometimes it works for me as well. It's still rather strange.